# Beautiful Soup Sometimes Return NoneType

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, google-colaboratory

I am trying to build a scraper for a school project to scrape lyrics on Genius, and I've found this piece of code:

```
def scrape_song_lyrics(url):
    page = requests.get(url)
    html = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    lyrics = html.find('div', class_='lyrics').get_text()
    #remove identifiers like chorus, verse, etc
    lyrics = re.sub(r'[\(\[].*?[\)\]]', '', lyrics)
    #remove empty lines
    lyrics = os.linesep.join([s for s in lyrics.splitlines() if s])         
    return lyrics
```

I'm running it in Google Colab, however, I'm encountering issues where it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't, the error is  `'NoneType' has no attribute 'get_text'`, I assume it's because of the HTML is not loaded properly.
I know there's quite a few questions on this topic, and a lot of answers including using `urllib.request`, `selenium`, but none worked for me.

I'm especially curious as to why sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. I've re-started run times a few times, and there are times when everything works like a charm, and there are times where it just doesn't work, and I made no changes to the code between the two scenarios.
I need to **scrape** a lot of songs (about 10,000) so I really need this scraper to work and be reliable, thanks in advance!

Comment: HTML requests do not always succeed and may need to be retried.  When it fails, do you get NO data, or is it just that the `div` you need is missing?

Comment: Interesting that you have a school project inviting you to violate copyright law, especially when Genius has already sued Google over this kind of scraping.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that the server returns two version of the HTML page. To get lyrics from both versions, you can use this example:

```
import os
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  

def scrape_song_lyrics(url):
    page = requests.get(url)
    html = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
    lyrics = html.select_one(
        'div[class^="lyrics"], div[class^="SongPage__Section"]'
    ).get_text(separator="\n")
    # remove identifiers like chorus, verse, etc
    lyrics = re.sub(r"[\(\[].*?[\)\]]", "", lyrics)
    # remove empty lines
    lyrics = os.linesep.join([s for s in lyrics.splitlines() if s])
    return lyrics
```

---

For testing you can use for example:

```
url = "https://genius.com/Billie-eilish-your-power-lyrics"

for i in range(100):
    print(scrape_song_lyrics(url))
    print(i, "-" * 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

In line 3, `lyrics = lyrics = html.find('div', class_='lyrics').get_text()` you can see that it's calling `html.find('div', class='lyrics')` first and then calling `.get_text()` method on that. There might be pages in the target site where the HTML parser can't find the div and it's returning `None` in that case. There might be multiple reasons why the parser can't find the target div. It can be because the div doesn't exist or it can be because the parser can't find it within an implicit time limit.

When you're trying to call `.get_text()` on the `None`, python is raising the `AttributeError`.

You've to deal with these types of errors in your web scraping code all the time. What you can do is—handle the error and ignore that since it's expected. You can do something like this:

```
def scrape_song_lyrics(url):
    page = requests.get(url)
    html = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    
    try:
        lyrics = html.find('div', class_='lyrics').get_text()
    except AttributeError:
        print('cannot find the target div: lyrics')
        return None
    
    else:
        #remove identifiers like chorus, verse, etc
        lyrics = re.sub(r'[\(\[].*?[\)\]]', '', lyrics)
        #remove empty lines
        lyrics = os.linesep.join([s for s in lyrics.splitlines() if s]) 
        return lyrics
```

This will return `None` when the error occurs instead of throwing an attribute error. Then if you want you can write a retry logic where the caller will retry running the callee if it returns `None`.